# Use of unicode predefined character classes in Boost Spirit

Tags: boost, unicode, boost-spirit, lexer

I am trying to use the letter character class from unicode i.e. \p{L} with Boost Spirit but I have no luck so far. Below is an example where I am trying to use (on line 30) the \p{L} character class. When I replace line 30 with line 29 it works but that is not the intended use as I need any letter from Unicode in my example.
My use case is for UTF8 only. At the end of they day what I am trying to do here is substract a unicode range from all unicode letters when using boost-spirit lexer.

PS
Of course, my example is trimmed down and may not make a lot of sense as a use case but I hope you get the idea.

```
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>

#include <boost/spirit/include/lex_lexertl.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/std_pair.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>

using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::spirit;
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

std::vector<pair<string, string> > getTokenMacros() {

    std::vector<pair<string, string> > tokenDefinitionsVector;

    tokenDefinitionsVector.emplace_back("JAPANESE_HIRAGANA", "[\u3041-\u3096]");
    tokenDefinitionsVector.emplace_back("JAPANESE_HIRAGANA1",
            "[\u3099-\u309E]");

    tokenDefinitionsVector.emplace_back("ASIAN_NWS", "{JAPANESE_HIRAGANA}|"
            "{JAPANESE_HIRAGANA1}");

    tokenDefinitionsVector.emplace_back("ASIAN_NWS_WORD", "{ASIAN_NWS}*");

    //tokenDefinitionsVector.emplace_back("NON_ASIAN_LETTER", "[A-Za-z0-9]");
    tokenDefinitionsVector.emplace_back("NON_ASIAN_LETTER", "[\\p{L}-[{ASIAN_NWS}]]");

    tokenDefinitionsVector.emplace_back("WORD", "{NON_ASIAN_LETTER}+");
    tokenDefinitionsVector.emplace_back("ANY", ".");

    return tokenDefinitionsVector;
}
;

struct distance_func {
    template<typename Iterator1, typename Iterator2>
    struct result: boost::iterator_difference<Iterator1> {
    };

    template<typename Iterator1, typename Iterator2>
    typename result<Iterator1, Iterator2>::type operator()(Iterator1& begin,
            Iterator2& end) const {
        return distance(begin, end);
    }
};

boost::phoenix::function<distance_func> const distance_fctor = distance_func();

template<typename Lexer>
struct word_count_tokens: lex::lexer<Lexer> {
    word_count_tokens() :
            asianNwsWord("{ASIAN_NWS_WORD}", lex::min_token_id + 110), word(
                    "{WORD}", lex::min_token_id + 170), any("{ANY}",
                    lex::min_token_id + 3000) {
        using lex::_start;
        using lex::_end;
        using boost::phoenix::ref;

        std::vector<pair<string, string> > tokenMacros(getTokenMacros());
        for (auto start = tokenMacros.begin(), end = tokenMacros.end();
                start != end; start++) {
            this->self.add_pattern(start->first, start->second);
        }

        this->self = asianNwsWord | word | any;
    }

    lex::token_def<> asianNwsWord, word, any;

};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    typedef lex::lexertl::token<string::iterator> token_type;
    typedef lex::lexertl::actor_lexer<token_type> lexer_type;

    word_count_tokens<lexer_type> word_count_lexer;

    // read in the file int memory
    ifstream sampleFile("/home/dan/Documents/wikiSample.txt");

    string str = "abc efg ぁあ";
    string::iterator first = str.begin();
    string::iterator last = str.end();

    lexer_type::iterator_type iter = word_count_lexer.begin(first, last);
    lexer_type::iterator_type end = word_count_lexer.end();

    typedef boost::iterator_range<string::iterator> iterator_range;
    vector<iterator_range> parsed_tokens;

    while (iter != end && token_is_valid(*iter)) {
        cout << (iter->id() - lex::min_token_id) << " " << iter->value()
                << endl;
        const iterator_range range = get<iterator_range>(iter->value());
        parsed_tokens.push_back(range);
        ++iter;
    }

    if (iter != end) {
        string rest(first, last);
        cout << endl << "!!!!!!!!!" << endl << "Lexical analysis failed\n"
                << "stopped at: \"" << rest << "\"" << endl;
        cout << "#" << (int) rest.at(0) << "#" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```